# jsonpath using regular expressions in Talend 5.5

Tags: java, regex, json, talend, jsonpath

I have this json string:

I want to extract all the ids that are after the node of number:`"0"`,`"1"`,`"2"`...etc.

I have succeeded to get a single id by using jsonpath: `$.response.data.0.id` and got `"15124"`.
but i'm looking for a jsonpath that will extract all the ids in the Json String.
in other words this is the expexted output: `15124`,`13498`,`14296`,`13364`,`14060`,`13672`.

This is the Json String i have:

```
{
"response": {
    "code": 200,
    "msg": "Success",
    "data": {
        "0": {
            "id": "15124",
            "name": " yoav (yoavshaki@yahoo.com) - 301519506662355",
            "network_id": 1,
            "network_type": "Facebook",
            "currency": "USD",
            "currency_info": {
                "prefix": "$",
                "postfix": "",
                "name": "US Dollars"
            },
            "timezone": {
                "id": 139,
                "code": "IST",
                "region": "Asia",
                "locality": "Jerusalem",
                "offset": 3,
                "facebook_code": 70
            }
        },
        "1": {
            "id": "13498",
            "name": "(Not in used) Daniel - 30138444",
            "network_id": 1,
            "network_type": "Facebook",
            "currency": "USD",
            "currency_info": {
                "prefix": "$",
                "postfix": "",
                "name": "US Dollars"
            },
            "timezone": {
                "id": 92,
                "code": "PST",
                "region": "America",
                "locality": "Los_Angeles",
                "offset": -7,
                "facebook_code": 1
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "id": "14296",
            "name": "Daniel - ComeOn (bingocafe@walla.com - 1375713835981039)",
            "network_id": 1,
            "network_type": "Facebook",
            "currency": "USD",
            "currency_info": {
                "prefix": "$",
                "postfix": "",
                "name": "US Dollars"
            },
            "timezone": {
                "id": 92,
                "code": "PST",
                "region": "America",
                "locality": "Los_Angeles",
                "offset": -7,
                "facebook_code": 1
            }
        },
        "3": {
            "id": "13364",
            "name": "Erez - 116060088528093",
            "network_id": 1,
            "network_type": "Facebook",
            "currency": "USD",
            "currency_info": {
                "prefix": "$",
                "postfix": "",
                "name": "US Dollars"
            },
            "timezone": {
                "id": 92,
                "code": "PST",
                "region": "America",
                "locality": "Los_Angeles",
                "offset": -7,
                "facebook_code": 1
            }
        },
        "4": {
            "id": "14060",
            "name": "Erez - NordicBet (gianniciano82@gmail.com - 105134566315107)",
            "network_id": 1,
            "network_type": "Facebook",
            "currency": "USD",
            "currency_info": {
                "prefix": "$",
                "postfix": "",
                "name": "US Dollars"
            },
            "timezone": {
                "id": 139,
                "code": "IST",
                "region": "Asia",
                "locality": "Jerusalem",
                "offset": 3,
                "facebook_code": 70
            }
        },
        "5": {
            "id": "13672",
            "name": "Erez - alon.dan - 1378526859026272",
            "network_id": 1,
            "network_type": "Facebook",
            "currency": "USD",
            "currency_info": {
                "prefix": "$",
                "postfix": "",
                "name": "US Dollars"
            },
            "timezone": {
                "id": 92,
                "code": "PST",
                "region": "America",
                "locality": "Los_Angeles",
                "offset": -7,
                "facebook_code": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for all the helpers!

Comment: Have you tried `$.response.data.*.id`?

Comment: @nerdwaller No, it's the syntax of the Java library [jsonpath](https://code.google.com/p/json-path/).

Comment: And you have tried ... what, so far? Please don't come here to make someone else write your code for you.

Comment: `$.response.data.*.id` will work.

Answer (score 1):

[GSON library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is a good option to convert java object to json string and vise versa.

- for converting json to java object use: [fromJson(String, Class)](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class))
- for converting java object to json string use: [toJson(Object)](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson(java.lang.Object))

Here is the sample code using [Gson#fromJson()] to convert JSON string into java Map.

[Find more examples...](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/)

Sample code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("resources/json.txt")));
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map = gson.fromJson(reader, type);

Map<String, Map<String, Object>> innerMap = (Map<String, Map<String, Object>>) map.get("response").get("data");
for (String key : innerMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("key:" + key + " id:" + innerMap.get(key).get("id"));
}
```

output:

```
key:0 id:15124
key:1 id:13498
key:2 id:14296
key:3 id:13364
key:4 id:14060
key:5 id:13672
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Syam S. for your answer.

`$.response.data.*.id` indeed work!

Comment: You should thank the user in the comments, not post a new answer.